# Blazor - Downloaded PDFs Are Corrupted But Image Files Are Fine

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, download, blazor

This one has me stumped. I am following Microsoft documentation here but for some reason, I'm still getting corrupted PDFs when they are downloaded from a Blazor server application. Image files (at least PNGs so far) download and open just fine. Any document that is uploaded is stored in an MS SQL database with the varbinary(max) data type assigned and is represented by a byte[] in C#.

Here is the code that reads the PDF (both the HTML and C# pieces):

```cs
public async void OnHardwarePurchaseWarrantySupportingDocumentChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs inputFileChangeEventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        foreach(IBrowserFile file in inputFileChangeEventArgs.GetMultipleFiles(inputFileChangeEventArgs.FileCount))
        {
            Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size);

            HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentData = new byte[stream.Length];

            await stream.ReadAsync(HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentData, 0, HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentData.Length);

            HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentName = file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - (file.Name.Length - file.Name.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal)));
            HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentFileExtension = file.Name.Substring(file.Name.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal), file.Name.Length - file.Name.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal));

            stream.Close();

            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception fe)
    {
        Log.LogError(fe.Message, fe);
        Modal.ShowErrorModal("File Upload Failure", "The selected file could not be uploaded due to an error. Please try again. If the error persist, please contact support.", false, false, false, delegate {});
    }
    finally{
        Throbber.IsSpinning = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <InputFile type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.tiff,.bmp,.doc,.docx,.pdf"  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-1 rounded border-dark" OnChange="@OnHardwarePurchaseWarrantySupportingDocumentChange"/>
        <small class="fw-bold">Supporting Document</small>
        <br/>
        <small>
            Supports the following file formats
            <br/>
            jpg, jpeg, png, tiff, bmp, doc, docx, pdf
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the code that is suppose to download the document for opening and viewing (both the C# and JavaScript pieces):

```cs
public async Task DownloadHardwarePurchaseWarrantySupportingDocumentData()
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(HardwarePurchaseWarranty.SupportingDocumentData);
        using DotNetStreamReference memoryStreamReference = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: memoryStream);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.DownloadFile", HardwarePurchaseWarranty.SupportingDocumentName + HardwarePurchaseWarranty.SupportingDocumentFileExtension, memoryStreamReference);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.LogError(e.Message);
        Modal.ShowErrorModal("Program Error", "Unexpected error trying to download file. If the issue persist, please contact support.", true, false, false, delegate {});
    }
}
```

```js
window.DownloadFile = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
   const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
   const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
   const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
   anchorElement.href = url;
   anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
   anchorElement.click();
   anchorElement.remove();
   URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Can anyone spot the issue here?

Comment: Corrupted how? Is the PDF the same number of bytes after this process or not? If so, what bytes have changed and how?

Comment: In my testing and changing of code around I either get a "Failed to load PDF document" message or the PDF opens but pages (14 total in this scenario) are blank.

Comment: Also, yes the number of bytes are the same. If I upload a document in memory and immediate download it, I get the same result.

Comment: @osswmi I have exactly same problem.

Comment: @DavidShochet See the answer I posted below. I meant to post it after the initial testing was completed but it fell off my radar until your comment came through.

Answer (score 0):

After working with a fellow coworker, we were able to resolve the issue. Below is the final code with an explanation of the changes needed to resolve this issue.

This is the HTML code using the InputFile component:

```html
<InputFile type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.tiff,.bmp,.doc,.docx,.pdf"  OnChange="@OnDocumentChange"/>
```

This is the C# code to obtain the target file and what had to be recoded properly in order to read the file without corrupting it:

```cs
public async void OnDocumentChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs inputFileChangeEventArgs)
{
    foreach (IBrowserFile file in inputFileChangeEventArgs.GetMultipleFiles(inputFileChangeEventArgs.FileCount))
    {
        Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size * 1024);
        HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentData = new byte[stream.Length];

        // the next three lines below were the solution for us. the 'await stream.async' in the original post was not the correct method.
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentData);
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Close();

        HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentName = file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - (file.Name.Length - file.Name.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal)));
        HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentFileExtension = file.Name.Substring(file.Name.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal), file.Name.Length - file.Name.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal));

        stream.Close();

        // this example only allows one file upload, modify the foreach loop to handle multiple files accordingly
        break;
    }
}
```

Now to properly download the file, you need a JavaScript handler inside your CSTHML layout view like so:

```js
window.DownloadFile = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
    const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = url;
    anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

Then to download your file back out from Blazor, in your C# code you will make a JSInterop call like the following:

```cs
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentData);
using DotNetStreamReference memoryStreamReference = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: memoryStream);
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.DownloadFile", HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentName + HardwarePurchaseWarrantyCreate.SupportingDocumentFileExtension, memoryStreamReference);
```